# Calling GetID with amazon cognito in ios

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I am following this blog post from amazon: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication

I have this set up:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"IdentityPool"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

In iOS how do I call GetID?

Comment: Not to self is do not use the IdentityPool Name but instead the pool Id provided in the sample code would indeed help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `getId` and then refresh the credentials. First do:

Obj-C:

```
// Retrieve your Amazon Cognito ID
[[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    }
    else {
        // the task result will contain the identity id
        NSString *cognitoId = task.result;
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Swift:

```
// Retrieve your Amazon Cognito ID
credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if (task.error != nil) {
        print("Error: " + task.error.localizedDescription)
    }
    else {
        // the task result will contain the identity id
        let cognitoId = task.result
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then refresh:

```
- (BFTask *)getIdentityId {
    if (self.identityId) {
        return [BFTask taskWithResult:self.identityid];
    } else {
        return [[BFTask taskWithResult:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            if (!self.identityId) {
                return [self refresh];
            }
            return [BFTask taskWithResult:self.identityid];
        }];
    }
}

- (BFTask *)refresh {
    return [[BFTask taskWithResult:nil] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
          // make a call to your backend, passing logins on provider
          MyLoginResult *result = [MyLogin login:user password:password withLogins:self.logins];
          // results should contain identityid and token, set them on the provider
          self.token = result.token;
          self.identityId = result.identityId;
          // not required, but returning the identityId is useful
          return [BFTask taskWithResult:self.identityid]; 
    }];
}
```

From documentation [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html)

Comment: Is this still relevant: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication